# Why am I getting 'NameError: name 'alarmthresh5' not defined in code with Function and Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, function, variables, global

I am a beginner and am getting this error when I run my code in main_odroid.py:

'NameError: name 'alarmthresh5' is not defined'

When i run this code:

```
from threading import Thread

def func3():
    Import main_odroid
    global alarmthresh5
    alarmthresh5 = 1.45 * stddev2

[...]
if floats[1] > alarmthresh5:
   wpi.digitalWrite(1, 1)
[...]
Thread(target = func3).start()
[...]
```

[...] means the rest of the (irrelevant) code that I excluded for clarity.

I used the search function and tried different answers but it did not solve the problem.
Thanks I and I am interested in your answers.

EDIT: scope of variable alarmthresh5 is global i think, because I typed 'global alarmthresh5' in func3.

EDIT2: The entire code

```
import subprocess                                           
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE         
import os                                             
import odroid_wiringpi as wpi
from collections import deque
import time
import datetime
from threading import Thread
from math import sqrt

sysdamping = 10
freqdamping = 14 
totalbins = 2000

#Functions
def average(p): return sum(p) / float(len(p))
def variance(p): return list(map(lambda x: (x - average(p))**2, p)) 
def std_dev(p): return sqrt(average(variance(p)))

wpi.wiringPiSetup()          
wpi.pinMode(1, 1) 
wpi.pinMode(5, 1)
wpi.pinMode(27, 1)
wpi.pinMode(31, 1) 
wpi.pinMode(23, 1) 
wpi.pinMode(11, 1) 
wpi.digitalWrite(23, 0) 
wpi.digitalWrite(11, 0)
wpi.pinMode(2, 1) 
wpi.pinMode(7, 1) 
wpi.digitalWrite(2, 0) 
wpi.digitalWrite(7, 0) 

wpi.pinMode(9, 1) 
wpi.digitalWrite(9, 0)  
time.sleep(0.1)

wpi.pullUpDnControl(30, 2)                 

os.system("killall -9 soapy_power -q")
time.sleep(0.1)

def func2():
    exec(open("/home/odroid/rtl-power-fftw/build/deactiveer.py").read())

def func3():
    import main_odroid
    global alarmthresh1
    global alarmthresh2
    global alarmthresh3
    global alarmthresh4
    global alarmthresh5
    global Lijst
    alarmthresh1 = (average(rolling[i]) + 1.45 * stddev2)       
    alarmthresh2 = alarmthresh1 + 2
    alarmthresh3 = alarmthresh2 + 2
    alarmthresh4 = alarmthresh3 + 2
    alarmthresh5 = alarmthresh4 + 2
    Lijst = [381843000.0, 382242000.0, 382245000.0, 382248000.0, 382254000.0, 382257000.0, 382305000.0, 382308000.0, 382320000.0, 382323000.0, 382326000.0, 382389000.0, 382392000.0, 382557000.0, 382560000.0, 382671000.0, 383157000.0, 383454000.0, 383457000.0, 383469000.0, 383472000.0, 383997000.0, 384000000.0, 384003000.0, 384006000.0]

def func4():
    import main_odroid
    global stddev2
    stddev2 = std_dev(sweep)

def func1():                                       
    cmd = ["/home/odroid/.local/bin/soapy_power", "-f", "433M", "-r", "6M", "--force-rate", "-q", "-c", "-b", "2000", "-F", "rtl_power_fftw"]          
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)                               

    rolling = []    
    i = 0
    rolling_avg = deque([])

    sweep = deque([], maxlen=1500)      
    stddev = 12  
    totalbins = 2000

    # Let's see what's going on with rtl_power_fftw   
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
        #Ignore garbage output
        if not (b'#' in line or not line.strip()):
            floats = list(map(float, line.split()))   

            # Create 2D array         
            if len(rolling) < totalbins:     
                rolling.append(deque([]))    
            rolling[i].append(floats[1])    
            sweep.append(floats[1])        
            # Let's start filtering...

            if len(rolling[i]) >= freqdamping:
                rolling[i].popleft()
                print("ref 5")
                input_state3 = wpi.digitalRead(9)    

                if floats[1] > alarmthresh5 and 380820000.0 < floats[0] < 384570000.0 and floats[0] not in Lijst:   # Led 5
                    wpi.digitalWrite(1, 1)
                    if input_state3 == 0:                     
                        wpi.digitalWrite(9, 1) # Buzzer proxy
                        wpi.digitalWrite(31, 1) # Buzzer ON   
                        print(round(floats[0]), round(floats[1]), alarmthresh5, "ref2")  
                        Thread(target = func2).start()
                if floats[1] > alarmthresh1 and floats[0] in [380310000.0, 381444000.0, 381579000.0, 381780000.0, 381783000.0, 382110000.0, 382836000.0, 382881000.0, 382884000.0, 382887000.0, 382890000.0, 382893000.0, 383037000.0, 383085000.0, 383340000.0, 383460000.0, 384258000.0, 384261000.0, 384264000.0]:
                    if input_state3 == 0:
                        wpi.digitalWrite(9, 1) # Buzzer proxy
                        wpi.digitalWrite(31, 1) # Buzzer ON
                        print(round(floats[0]), round(floats[1]), alarmthresh1, "ref1")
                        Thread(target = func2).start()

                if floats[1] > alarmthresh4 and 380820000.0 < floats[0] < 384570000.0 and floats[0] not in Lijst:     # Led 4                                                            
                    wpi.digitalWrite(7, 1)
                if floats[1] > alarmthresh3 and 380820000.0 < floats[0] < 384570000.0 and floats[0] not in Lijst:     # Led 3                       
                    wpi.digitalWrite(23, 1)
                if floats[1] > alarmthresh2 and 380820000.0 < floats[0] < 384570000.0 and floats[0] not in Lijst:     # Led 2                      
                    wpi.digitalWrite(5, 1)
                if floats[1] > alarmthresh1 and 380820000.0 < floats[0] < 384570000.0 and floats[0] not in Lijst:     # Led 1                         
                    input_state = wpi.digitalRead(27)    
                    if input_state == 0:                      
                        wpi.digitalWrite(27, 1)
                        Thread(target = func2).start()

            # Increment or reset indexer (i)
            if i < totalbins - i: i = i + 1
            else:
                i = 0
                Thread(target = func4).start()  # Set stddev2
                Thread(target = func3).start()  # Set alarmthresh1 - alarmthresh5
                print("ref 6")

    p.stdout.close()
    p.wait()
Thread(target = func1).start()
```

Ref 6 prints before ref 5, so func3 is started before alarmthresh5 is called.

Comment: Which line fails? If its `if floats[1] > alarmthresh5:` and you haven't called `func3` at least once, there's your problem. I think this is a good case for simply pulling `alarmthresh5` out to the top of the module with a default value.

Comment: It is 'if floats[1] > alarmthresh5', but this part of the code should be run later than the part with 'Thread(target = func3).start()' because of an if statement. 'if floats[1] > alarmthresh5' is under the if statement 'if length(rolling[i]) > freqdamping'.    Will try giving alarmthresh5 a default value in the top.

Comment: A working example would help. I know nothing of how you started the thread or where the problem is. Perhaps this is a race condition where the thread hasn't had a chance to set the variable. Its generally risky to have threads communicate on a global variable. You really have to sort out all of the timing.

Comment: I will upload the entire code. I added alarmthresh = -70 as an initial value in the top of thr code but print(alarmthresh5) keeps printing -70 so it does not appear to be calculating alarmthresh5 in func3.

Comment: Added entire code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify scope of variable alarmthresh5. Try to add variable in function definition only, something like this: def func3(alarmthresh5=valueyouwantotput)

Comment: The scope of alarmthresh5 is global, i think, because although it is mentioned in the function, i added 'global alarmthresh5' in func3.   Putting alarmthreshold=valueyouWantToPut is not going to work because the value wil constantly change (because stddev2 changes)